# Cell table link to TOC

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, hyperref, hyperlink, hypertarget

I need to link a particular cell of a table to the toc. For example, `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Pablo}` or `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{prudencia}`. My code:

```
            \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[textheight=24cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{booktabs,newtxtext,newtxmath,multirow}
    \usepackage{ltablex}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{pdfpages}   
    \pdfminorversion=7
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
    \newcommand{\hc}[1]{\hspace{#1 cm}\textquotedbl}
    \newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1}
    \newcommand{\np}[1]{$^\mathbf{#1}$}
    \usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}
    \makeatletter

    \patchcmd{\l@section}
      {\hfill}
      {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}
      \hfill}
      {}{}
    \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
        \begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\contentsname
            \@mkboth{%
               \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]%
        \@starttoc{toc}%
        \end{multicols}%
        }
    \makeatother 
    
    \usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=,linkcolor=blue}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

    \begin{document}
    
    \includepdf[width=\textwidth]{./mw1}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents

    \definecolor{prejilla}{HTML} {cc6699}
    \definecolor{pnon}    {HTML} {a0d6b4}
    \definecolor{ppar}    {HTML} {ffffd7}
    \definecolor{ptexto}  {HTML} {8b008c}

    \newcommand{\cp}[1]{%
      \rowcolor{\pparOrpnon}
      \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \else
        \stepcounter{prowcolors}%
      \fi
      #1
    }
    \newcommand{\pparOrpnon}{%
      \ifodd\value{prowcolors}ppar\else pnon\fi
    }
    \newcounter{prowcolors}
    
    \newcommand{\rp}[3]{\cp{#1} & #2 & #3}     %   p-row
    
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{P}
    
    \newpage
    %-----the table:
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
      !{\color{prejilla}\VRule[ 1pt]}>{\bfseries\color{black}}l                   
      !{\color{prejilla}\VRule[.7pt]}>{\color{black}}l
      !{\color{prejilla}\VRule[.7pt]}>{\color{black}}X
      !{\color{prejilla}\VRule[1pt]}}          
    
    \arrayrulecolor{prejilla}                
    
    \specialrule{4pt}{0pt}{0pt}                 
    \rowcolor{pnon}                    
     
    \rp{Concepto}{\bfseries Clave}{}{\bfseries Cita}\\
    
    \specialrule{4pt}{0pt}{0pt}

    \rp{Pablo}          {caballero}            {San Pablo, c} \\ 
    \rp{paciencia}      {ausencia}             {¿Y quién prueba mi paciencia?  Ausencia} \\ 
    \rp{prudencia}      {amar}                 {¿Es necedad amar? No es gran prudencia 25} \\ 
    \rp{}               {Quijote}              {él va encantado en esta carreta, no por sus culpas y pecados, sino por la mala} \\ 
    \rp{}               {Sancho}               {el asendereado Sancho Panza, gobernador, por sus pecados y por su mala andanza, de la ínsula de Barataria} \\ 
    \rp{}               {sima}                 {traeré quien te saque de esta sima, donde tus pecados te deben haber puesto} \\ 
    \rp{}               {triunfan}             {pero triunfan ahora, por pecados de las gentes, la pereza, la ociosidad, la gula y el regalo} \\ 
    \rp{pecador}        {enmendarse}           {los pecadores discretos están más cerca de enmendarse que los simples} \\ 
    \rp{}               {hipócrita}            {menos mal hace el hipócrita que se finge bueno que el público pecador} \\ 
    \rp{}               {muchos}               {son muchos los pecadores que se usan} \\ 
    \rp{}               {soberbio}             {préciate más de ser humilde virtuoso que pecador soberbio 868} \\ 
    \rp{pecar}          {desayunar}            {no me he desayunado, si de pecar no 468} \\ 
    \rp{pecho}          {matar envidia}        {Hemos de matar a la envidia, en la generosidad y buen pecho 606 (v fama)} \\ 
    \rp{}               {mostrar}              {Por esto querría que la fortuna me hiciese emperador, por mostrar mi pecho haciendo bien a mis amigos 512 (v mostrar)} \\ 
    \rp{pedir}          {consejos}             {no deis consejos a quien no os los pide 1025} \\ 
    \rp{}               {saber}                {Aprendan, aprendan mucho de enhoramala a saber rogar y a saber pedir y a tener crianza 827} \\ 
      
    \specialrule{4pt}{0pt}{0pt}                  
    \end{tabularx}                               
    \end{center}                                 
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Don't simply dump your document on people that should help you, make an effort to create a short and concise question. 300 lines of code to describe such a problem is way too much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If only some cell needs to be linked in the ToC you can use

```
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \begin{multicols*}{2}[\section*{\contentsname % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \@mkboth{%
                \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]%
        \@starttoc{toc}%
    \end{multicols*}%
}
```

and

```
\rp{Pablo\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Pablo}}          {caballero}            {San Pablo, c} \\
```

to get

[image: a]

Comment: I had already tested your kind suggestion but, the link takes me to the beginning of the table, and not to the page where the word is. How could I fix this?

Comment: @Antonio Ortiz It takes you to the linked cell, as you asked.

Comment: Yes, in the example I sent the link takes you to the only page the code generates . But, I have a 25 tables with nearly 5000 quotes. I did what you suggested and takes me to the beginning of the corresponding table, but not the correct page. Excuse me if I insist. I greatly appreciate your kind support. Thank you, and hope you can help me.

Comment: I found that the stared version of "multicols" was not necessary. Just adding the command ```\phantomsection``` gives the desire result. For example:   ```key_word\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{key_word}```

Comment: The starred version was to have avoid the balancing columns: so the Pablo goes bellow the P instead of its right side.

Answer (score 0):

To set a target for a link you should use `\phantomsection` (as you do earlier in your code). So e.g.

```
\rp{\phantomsection%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{prudencia}%
    prudencia}      {amar}                 {¿Es necedad amar? No es gran prudencia 25}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I obtained with: `key_word\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{key_word}` :
[image: index]